# Why won't my form display in Visual Studio 2010 when debugging my project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I have one form (and its associated vb file) and another, separate vb file. When I go to compile and debug my code, my building succeeds, and the form displays, but the "ball" doesn't move.

My startup class:

```
Public Class Bouncer

    Private bouncingBall As Ball

    Private Sub CST8333_Lab3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bouncingBall = New Ball(Me)
        'Me.Controls.Add(Ball)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        bouncingBall.MoveBall()
    End Sub
End Class
```

My other, separate class:

```
Public Class Ball

    Private ballX As Integer
    Private ballY As Integer
    Private ballMovementX As Integer
    Private ballMovementY As Integer
    Private _bouncer As Bouncer

    Sub New(bouncer As Bouncer)
        _bouncer = bouncer
        ballX = 50
        ballY = 50
        ballMovementX = 5
        ballMovementY = 5
    End Sub

    Public Function GetBallX() As Integer
        Return ballX
    End Function

    Public Sub MoveBall()
        If (ballX >= _bouncer.Width) Then
            ballMovementX = -ballMovementX
        ElseIf (ballX <= 0) Then
            ballMovementX = -ballMovementX
        End If
        If (ballY >= _bouncer.Height) Then
            ballMovementY = -ballMovementY
        ElseIf (ballY <= 0) Then
            ballMovementY = -ballMovementY
        End If
        ballX += ballMovementX
        ballY += ballMovementY
    End Sub
End Class
```

My form displays, but my "ball" doesn't move. What I would like is for the variables and subroutines in my Ball class to control the movement of my Label "ball". Any help, suggestions?

Comment: What form? Not one reference to any form anywhere in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a timer instead of the `While True` loop.  The `While True` loop isn't giving the GUI a chance to update the screen.

Assuming `Ball` is a control, it needs to be added to the form's collection:

```
bouncingBall = New Ball(Me)
Me.Controls.Add(bouncingBall)
bouncingBall.MoveBall()
```

It's unclear what your `Ball` class is doing.  It looks like it's just updating internal variables and not actually moving the control, which is what I'm suspecting your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My While loop is actually the issue here. If I comment it out, the form opens and displays. As for my ball, it doesn't seem to be a control, although I'd like it to be a label box, so would I have to extend Label in my Ball class, or would there be a better way to do that?

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider Different ways to accomplish that depending on what you want to accomplish.  You could just use a Panel or a PictureBox, or just draw in the Form's paint event your ball's coordinates.  In the timer event, just call the Invalidate method to call the paint event.

Comment: I'd prefer to use a label box. It's supposed to be a basic project, so I'd prefer to not deal with Paint(). I have the Ball class and would like to associate it with the Label control.

Comment: I am trying to use the Ball class to move a label control around the Form using a timer.

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider And what's the problem?  If you've changed your code, best edit your question with the relevant information.